# Strange result from a C++/MFC compiler in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I thought I knew VS 2008 C++ compiler really well:

```
CString str;
str.Empty();
LPCTSTR pStr = str.IsEmpty() ? NULL : str;
::MessageBox(NULL, pStr ? L"pStr is NOT null" : L"pStr is null", L"Result", MB_OK);
```

Can someone explain why am I getting this?

[image]

Comment: Same with VS2012. It seems to be the ternary operator that's affecting it - replace with `if/else` and all is fine. It looks like the ternary operator creates a `LPCTSTR` with NULL content rather than assigning NULL to a `LPCTSTR`. I've no idea why, so +1 for a good question with potential for gotchas.

Comment: Same thing happens in VS2010 also; `LPCTSTR pStr = str.IsEmpty() ? NULL : str.GetBuffer();` does return NULL -- very strange, I also hope someone can explain this!

Comment: Another workaround is to do `str.GetString();`

Comment: @Edward `GetBuffer()` returns a pointer to a **modifiable** buffer (`LPTSTR`). It is meant to be used only if you need to manually change the controlled character array. You **must** call `ReleaseBuffer()` when done. If you need a pointer to the non-mutable buffer (`LPCTSTR`) call `GetString()` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LPCTSTR pStr = str.IsEmpty() ? (LPCTSTR)NULL : str;` does return a `NULL`.

It looks like this happens because the two expressions are not of the same type; [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e4213hs1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says

> If both expressions are of pointer types or if one is a pointer type
>   and the other is a constant expression that evaluates to 0, pointer
>   conversions are performed to convert them to a common type

A quote from [a MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1601431a-0d4e-4fa7-bbf1-d7260a0afd3f/is-this-c-correct-conversion-?forum=vclanguage):

> 5.16-3- in the standard describes the type coercion taking place here; the expression (B ? E1 : E2) can only have a single type, so if the
>   types of expressions E1 and E2 are different, they must be coerced
>   into a common, safe type before evaluation of either expression
>   occurrs ... So, the type of E1 in this example is CString, and the
>   type of E2 is int. The process described in 5.16-3- eventually
>   concludes that the only safe type for both of these to convert to is
>   CString.

Comment: Well found! +1 for persistence - I know you quoted from MSDN but I see there's a C/C++ standard behind it so it must be similar with other compilers.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. One would expect at least a compiler warning in this case.